# Как организовать взаимодействие пользователей в реальном времени в игре для соц.сети?

Tags: ajax, php, html5, javascript, mysql

В общем решил я написать мини игру для социальных сетей с использованием `html (html5), js, ajax, php, mysql`. Опыта в этом деле нет, поэтому решил начать с вопросов. Например, предположим, что я хочу сделать игру крестики-нолики. Играют два игрока. Как организовать их взаимодействие между собой? Чтобы один игрок поставил крестик, а второй его увидел у себя в браузере на своём поле и т.д.

**У меня план такой**, примерно как в мини чатах делают. Начинается игра. Создаётся файл(или запись в БД) на сервере. Имя файла является одновременно идентификатором, который выдаётся двум игрокам. Дальше каждому игроку даётся по очереди 1 минута на установку 0 или х. А у второго игрока скрипт с помощью `ajax`, например, каждые 5 секунд делает запрос обновился файл или нет. Если обновился, то считывается результат и передаётся ход.

Вопросы:

1) Можно ли так делать? Может есть какие более удачные подходы?
2) Как подобные механизмы работают с применением `flash`, есть какие-либо особенности? (с `flash` не знаком и желания его осваивать нет) . 
3) Что лучше в этом случае использовать; БД или файлы?
P.S. Если знаете хорошие примеры, мануалы по разработке соц. игр с применением `js` и `html5`, буду рад увидеть ссылки.

Comment: Вот [ссылка](http://hashcode.ru/questions/47673/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) по вашей теме

Answer (score 2):

Вы не правы. Долбить каждые 5 секунд сервер нельзя. `Longpollig` вам в помощь. И использовать для этого не файлы, а `redis` например. А  способ сохранения не так важен.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS и WebSocket тебе помогут)
Только я не уверен, что сокеты смогут нормально работать с php, но вроде эта идея развивается, и если поискать, можно найти какое-нибудь решение.